# Box plot with Highcharts - TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I try create box plots using *highcharts*, based on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/Rferf/) example. I always get the following error message: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Highcharts.Chart')

Since I'm not that familiar with javascript, I cannot find the error. Can somebody help me here?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/462cf4/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/462cf4/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script>
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'boxplot'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Some title'
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10-14','15-19','20-24','25-29','30-34','35-39','40-44','45-49','50-54','55-59','60-64','65-69','70-74','75-76'],
            title: {
                text: 'position'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'score'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Observations',
            data: [
                [24,31,33,33,33],[20,30,32,33,34],[15,28,32,33,34],[11,27,32,33,34],[10,26,31,33,34],[9,25,31,33,34],[9,26,32,33,34],[8,26,32,33,34],[8,26,32,33,34],[4,24,31,33,33],[2,23,31,33,33],[2,21,30,32,33],[2,18,29,32,33],[2,15,28,32,33],[2,7,27,31,33],[2,2,25,31,32],[2,2,23,30,32],[2,2,21,28,31],[2,2,20,27,31],[2,2,17,26,30],[2,2,14,23,29],[2,2,3,22,  28],[2,2,2,21,27]
            ],
        }]
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing two things:

1. Add the jQuery library before loading the chart libraries

   ```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://github.highcharts.com/462cf4/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://github.highcharts.com/462cf4/highcharts-more.js"></script>
   ```
2. Load your scripts inside the document ready event

   ```
        <script>
               $(function() {
                   var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                       chart: {
                           renderTo: 'container',
                           type: 'boxplot'
                       },
                       title: {
                           text: 'Some title'
                       },
                       legend: {
                           enabled: false
                       },
                       xAxis: {
                           categories: ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10-14','15-19','20-24','25-29','30-34','35-39','40-44','45-49','50-54','55-59','60-64','65-69','70-74','75-76'],
                           title: {
                               text: 'position'
                           }
                       },
                       yAxis: {
                           title: {
                               text: 'score'
                           }
                       },
                       series: [{
                           name: 'Observations',
                           data: [
                               [24,31,33,33,33],[20,30,32,33,34],[15,28,32,33,34],[11,27,32,33,34],[10,26,31,33,34],[9,25,31,33,34],[9,26,32,33,34],[8,26,32,33,34],[8,26,32,33,34],[4,24,31,33,33],[2,23,31,33,33],[2,21,30,32,33],[2,18,29,32,33],[2,15,28,32,33],[2,7,27,31,33],[2,2,25,31,32],[2,2,23,30,32],[2,2,21,28,31],[2,2,20,27,31],[2,2,17,26,30],[2,2,14,23,29],[2,2,3,22,  28],[2,2,2,21,27]
                           ],
                       }]
                   });
               })

           </script>
   ```